# Unable to access /administrator in Joomla on localhost, error 403 forbidden access

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, joomla-3.4, joomla-3.3.x, joomla-3.5

I have received a zip file from someone which contain all the data for a Joomla site. And he asked me to do some CSS configurations to change the look of homepage. I unzipped the zip file an found a .sql file, a Joomla site folder and a .jpa backup file. I pasted that folder in xampp's htdocs folder and named it as `tp` and then imported the sql file in newly created database and and made changes in configuration file for database.

Now when I type `localhost/tp` the site runs successfully, but when I type `localhost/tp/administrator` it gives me `403 forbidden access error`. The short note is that it's my first experience with Joomla and I don't know how I can fix this. As mostly 403 error comes due to error in .htdocs file that's why I am giving the the code at the end of this question.

```
# @package      Joomla
# @copyright    Copyright (C) 2005 - 2012 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license      GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymLinks
## Mod_rewrite in use.
RewriteEngine On
# Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit attempts to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
## End - Custom redirects
##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##
# RewriteBase /
## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the request is for something within the component folder,
# or for the site root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
# requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
Action php /cgi-php53/php
AddHandler php53 .php
```

Comment: See if this post gives you any leads https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/107/troubleshooting-403-error-accessing-admin-panel

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the 403 page?  There are a few extensions, etc that can generate it and most of us would recognize those if we saw it.

Comment: Check for existence of `.htaccess` file in /administrator folder. If there is a  one, rename it to `htaccess.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

A few questions:

- Are you sure about the permissions on your website?
- What happens if you remove the `.htaccess` file from your main Joomla folder (the one that you pasted above)? Will the problem be fixed?
- Also, is there any `.htaccess` file under your administrator folder? If there is one, can you remove it and see if that helps?
- What happens if you rename the `plugins` folder to `plugins_old` - will it work? If yes, then your problem lies with a security plugin, and you should disable it from `phpMyAdmin` (it is in the `#__extensions` table).

Answer (score 1):

You also have .jpa backup file, so why are you taking such a headache of setting up Joomla your self.
Create the Site using the backup, follow the following link => https://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/test-site-akeeba-backup/

You need to follow the step4 as the first 3 steps show how to take backup to get .jpa file.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to try that have sometimes worked when I've had this happen to me:

- rename .htaccess to old.htaccess to disable it temporarily, and do the same if there is one in /administrator folder
- check your file permissions are OK
- try accessing the administrator with index.php included in the file path (e.g. localhost/tp/administrator/index.php ).